# Mixture of two Poisson distributions

Tags: regression, bayesian, mixed-model, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I would like to determine the mixing between two Poisson distribution means. I have $N$ observations that are drawn from two Poisson distributions. Each observation is drawn from one of the two Poisson distributions {$P(\lambda_1)$,$P(\lambda_2)$}. The probability that an observation is drawn from $P(\lambda_1)$ is $p$ and $1-p$ that it is drawn from $P(\lambda_2)$. My goal is to estimate $p$ given the $N$ observations. The easiest thing I can do is to sum all observations and compare the mean. However, what is the best way to do this? I have the feeling that there must be a better way. For each repetition I know that the chosen distribution has to be one of the two, so I should be able to also reject noise.

Example code to generate demo data in Python:

```py
import numpy as np

l1 = 1.5 # lambda parameter for poisson distribution 1
l2 = 2.0 # Lambda parameter for poisson distribution 2

p0_test = 0.8123
N = 2000
observations = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    if np.random.rand() < p0_test:
        lambda_selected = l2
    else:
        lambda_selected = l1
    observations[i] = np.random.poisson(lam=lambda_selected)

# Task: Estimate p0 from N given observations and given l1 and l2 are known
naive_estimate = (np.sum(observations)-l1*N)/(l2*N-l1*N)
print(naive_estimate)
```

Comment: So you *know* the two Poisson parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$? Or do they also need to be estimated from observations?

Comment: I know $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as I can measure them separately (of course up to a certain error).

Comment: The EM algorithm applies to this simple setting.

Comment: Is the EM algorithm numerically stable? How would one implement that and how does it compare e.g. to CNNs or Transformers for this task?

Comment: The method of moments is attractive here, because the mean and SD algebraically determine the $\lambda_i.$

Comment: What do you mean by numerically stable? EM returns a finite number of solutions, possibly a single one in this case, and depends on the starting value.